# How to automatically load files into SharePoint

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

We are having someone manually load weekly generated excel spreadsheets into SharePoint.  I'm sure there is a way to automate this.  I don't know a lot about SharePoint, and maybe it's really as simple as just knowing the folder SharePoint is moving the files to and copying them directly there.  Or maybe it requires some programming to get it automatically load new files put in a given directory into SharePoint.

Either way, I would just like someone to point me in the right direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to upload the file using the copy web service in SharePoint.  I am not sure what version of SharePoint you are running but I am assuming 2007.  Here is a sample [project](http://oricode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/upload-a-file-to-sharepoint-2007-using-webservices-with-a-specific-content-type/).

```
public void UploadFile(string destinationFolderPath,
                      byte[] fileBytes,
                      string fileName,
                      bool overwrite,
                      string sourceFileUrl,
                      string lastVersionUrl)
{

List<Sharepoint.FieldInformation> fields = new List<Sharepoint.FieldInformation>();
Sharepoint.FieldInformation fieldInfo;

fieldInfo = new Sharepoint.FieldInformation();
fieldInfo.Id = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBuiltInFieldId.Title;
fieldInfo.Value = "New title";
fieldInfo.DisplayName = "Title";
fieldInfo.Type = YetAnotherMigrationTool.Library.SP2007.Sharepoint.FieldType.Text;
fieldInfo.InternalName = "Title";
fields.Add(fieldInfo);

string[] url;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destinationFolderPath))
    url = new string[] { string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", _siteUrl, _name, fileName) };
else
    url = new string[] { string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}{3}", _siteUrl, _name,    destinationFolderPath, fileName) };
Sharepoint.CopyResult[] result;

Sharepoint.Copy service = new Sharepoint.Copy();
service.Url = _siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/Copy.asmx";
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Instance.User, Settings.Instance.Password);
service.Timeout = 600000;

uint documentId = service.CopyIntoItems(sourceFileUrl, url, fields.ToArray(), fileBytes, out result);
}

public void SetContentType(List<string> ids, string contentType)
{
ListsService.Lists service = new YetAnotherMigrationTool.Library.SP2007.ListsService.Lists();
service.Url = _siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Instance.User, Settings.Instance.Password);

string strBatch = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= ids.Count; i++)
{
    strBatch += @"<Method ID='"+i.ToString()+@"' Cmd='Update'><Field Name='ID'>" + ids[i-1] + "</Field><Field Name='ContentType'>"+contentType+"</Field></Method>";
}
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement elBatch = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Batch");
elBatch.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "10");
elBatch.SetAttribute("ViewName", "");
elBatch.InnerXml = strBatch;

result = service.UpdateListItems(_name, elBatch);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it's SP 2010.  Not sure if that makes a difference or not...

Comment: It should not.  The web services are still available.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a PowerShell script that copies the document into the document library via WebDav:

Assuming you have your document library at *http://server/SomeWeb/DocumentLibrary/Folder*:

```
copy-item somesheet.xlsx \\server\SomeWeb\DocumentLibrary\Folder
```

Comment: I actually have never used PowerShell before though I've often told myself I need to look into it.  Is 'copy-item' a powershell command or is it a function I would have to write?